# text file cannot be made a folder

Tags: python

test.txt cannot be made. I want to make a folder&text file when I write a directory in html's form like:

[image: form].

The code:

```
os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)

f = open(directory, 'w')
f.write("testtesttesttest")
f.close()
```

I want to make 0422 folder in /Users/xxx/Downloads,and test.txt in 0422 folder. 
But when I run the file and I put directory in the form, 0422 folder was made and test.txt "folder" was made in 0422 folder.

I want to make test.txt (text file) in the folders. What is the problem in the code? Directory's variable can be gotten /Users/xxx/Downloads/0422/test.txt ,so it is ok.

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first create the directories, then create the file:

```
import os

directory = '/Users/xxx/Downloads/free.txt'
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(directory), exist_ok=True)

with open(directory, 'w') as f:
   f.write('blah blah')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one addition of the open statement.

```
os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)

f = open(directory +'/test.txt', 'w')
f.write("testtesttesttest")
f.close()
```

We need to mention the text.txt somewhere

Comment: thank you for your answer.I did not want to fix txt's name of test.txt.I want to made text file's name is put in  form.For example,my ideal system is when I put /Users/xxx/Downloads/free.txt,free.txt is made in Download folder.